# tools to help minimize usage of macros in C++ programs

Tags: c++, refactoring, c-preprocessor, automated-refactoring

Different C++ style guides deprecate the use of C Preprocessor macros.

I know there are tools which help detect errors due to macro usage (CPPCHECKER, Check), and tools which provide refactoring in the presence of preprocessor directives (CSCout, XRefactory).

I was wondering if there are any refactoring tools that suggest alternatives (like inline functions, constant expressions) to macros in C++ programs.

Comment: I just wrote an answer about it citing the recent paper by Kumar, Sutton and Stroustrup, before I realized you were that paper's first author! You might have mentioned that as a reference in your question :-) Are you looking for a framework to automate your own tools?

Comment: I am looking for citations (of related tools), if there are any. so that i could write that in my thesis work. I searched but could not find any. Our framework (cpp2cxx) actually does a little bit of automation.

Comment: I see on GitHub you already are interfacing with Clang. Perhaps Coverity might be something to look at, but IIRC it's closed source, and I think they looked at potential bugs not at macros per se.

Answer (score 1):

Years later it seems that your work is being used as a basis for such tools since there were none present before.

[Macronator](http://cute-test.com/projects/macronator/wiki) which later became part of [Cevelop](https://www.cevelop.com/) IDE is a tool that can refactor object-like and function-like macros to equivalent c++11 expressions. They reference ["The demacrofier"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6405347&isnumber=6404866) paper by by Kumar, Sutton, and Stroustrup as a base for their software. I used it to remove ~15k macros from a codebase.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the reference? I'm curious to know.

Comment: It's in the first link: [Macronator](http://cute-test.com/projects/macronator/wiki)
Originally it was a part of CUTE unit testing framework, now they moved it to the [Cevelop IDE](https://www.cevelop.com/).

Comment: A similar functionality is apparently coming to Visual studio [next release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/26/convert-macros-to-constexpr/).